# How to authenticate to WIX-BLOG API?

Tags: api, restful, wix, webhook

So I need to get all my blog posts every 5 hours.

This looks like a way to go:

https://dev.wix.com/api/rest/wix-blog

The only thing I don't get is how to authenticate to this API so I get MY OWN blog posts?

From what I've read so far it looks like I need to create a public Wix App that has a consent screen, App URL, redirect URL, must be publicly available to all users, and must be reviewed by the WIX staff.

But this goes totally against the logic. Why would they want this? Apps are for other users not just to get my own access token.

Quotation:

> - Apps must be publicly available in the App Market; private apps will be rejected.
> - Apps should have clear documentation instructions (relevant to Wix users) and provide an email address for support.
> - Apps should use Wix billing services and should not bill outside of the Wix cycle. The pricing plans should be clear and not misleading.
> - Apps should not display ads (including ads for your product, third-party ads, or any info that isn’t relevant to Wix users).

It absolutely doesn't make sense to me if I just want to access my own blogs. Can you bring some light to this, please?

Comment: I doubt that Wix has such an API.   They want to make it as hard as possible for you to take your site to another host.   Last time I checked Wix never implement an "export site" feature so that users wouldn't be able to take their site to some other host.  I suspect that Wix doesn't have an API for fetching content for the same reason.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller This looks like a way to go https://dev.wix.com/api/rest/wix-blog/blog/post/get-post But it always brings me to creating an App (that must be available for all users and have a consent screen)... which is totally against the logic to me...

Comment: "It absolutely doesn't make sense to me" It may make sense business-wise if it doesn't make sense technically. "Can you bring some light to this, please?" Did you ask the primary actor about this, aka Wix itself? What was their reply?

Comment: As the owner of a web hosting business who regularly is asked to migrate sites from Wix to WordPress, I can confirm that they have a "you are stuck with us" business model.  This is why I advise people to stay away from the proprietary systems such as Wix, Squarespace and any "site-builder".